# Moving highchart to the left when there is a Y-axis title

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to put Y-Axis title on top right of the Y-Axis, right below the chart title. However, when I insert the axis title, the whole graph moves to the right. I tried to used spacingLeft to set the position of the chart, but nothing changes. Is there a way to keep the position of the chart even if I add the axis title?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        marginBottom: 80,
        spacingTop: 20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart title',
        y: -10
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
            align: 'high',
            rotation: 0,
            x: 100,
            y:-20
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'high',
            x: 0,
            y: -5
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m7rc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Min Sun Song, you can use offset property to reduce that gap.

```
offset: -120,
```

I've updated you fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/8m7rc/2/)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello Strikers, can you please tell me how to update the offset dynamically based on the length of the title or hoo to set x/offset so that title always begins at the starting position?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `marginLeft` property for a chart. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8m7rc/3/).